# How do the updates get applied to the extensions published for Google Chrome and Edge

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, microsoft-edge-extension, webextension-polyfill

I am developing a browser extension for Chrome and Edge using webextension's polyfill.
I intend to roll out few improvement related hot fixes and bugs after 1st release[that is to an already published app].

For Chrome I have found this:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/hosting/#updating - As per this, the Chrome Browser periodically checks for new versions of installed extensions and updates them without user intervention.

But I have an additional question, will the updates be applied without user intervention even when there is change(addition and subtraction) in `permissions` in the `manifest`?

For Edge, I had found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/auto-update - This is completely different from the Chrome'e update philosophy. Here, there is a need of having `update-url` as per the doc.

So, what's the correct behaviour in both cases.

PS: I am using manifest V3.

Comment: Do you publish your extension on Web Store? The doc for Chrome is for extensions published on Web Store, but the doc for Edge is for extensions hosted on your own web server.

Comment: @YuZhou Yes, I am looking the solution for extensions published in stores[not self-hosted]. For edge, I could not find any doc other than this.

Answer (score 0):

That doc you find for Edge doesn't apply to extensions that you publish using the [Partner Center](https://partner.microsoft.com/dashboard/microsoftedge/public/login?ref=dd) dashboard. You can use the dashboard to release updated versions to your users and to the Microsoft Edge Add-ons website. For more information, see [Update a Microsoft Edge extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/update-extension).